# How do I access active IWorkbenchWindow in BundleActivator's start method?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my BundleActivator's start method, I need to access the active IWorkbenchWindow to add an IPartListener to it. However, when the start() method is called,

```
Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
```

returns null.
I tried adding a IWindowListener to Workbench.getInstance(), but a window open event is never fired. Only a window activated event is fired when I switch to another program and back to eclipse.

How do I add the IPartListener properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
workbench.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
     if (window != null) {
       // do something
     }
   }
 });
```

(from [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIStartup.html))

Answer (score 1):

`Workbench` is an internal class and you should not be using it ([Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)). Internal classes may be changed without notice (Workbench in fact was completely rewritten between Eclipse 3 or 4).

The official way to get the `IWorkbench` interface is:

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
```

However this may also return null if it is called too early in the Eclipse startup.

It is not usual to add a part listener in an activator, usually this is done in a view or editor part initialization or in a command handler or action.